# Select fields when importing CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following CSV import action in my Miniatures model

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Miniature.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
```

That works fine but what I want to do is use further columns in the CSV to create associated objects.

This is one of my attempts:

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Miniature.create! row.to_hash.slice(row[0..10])
      @miniature.sizes.build(:scale_id => row[11])
    end
  end
```

My attempted at slicing the row have been very unsuccessful. If I don't slice off the first 10 rows then the Miniature.create tries to parse the 11th column which only applies to the associated sizes model. I want to slice off the first 10 and create a Miniature object with them and then build or create a line in my Sizes join table with the supplied scale_id.

Any help very much appreciated.

**Another Update**

This is my latest and cleanest attempt:

```
Miniature.create! row.to_hash.except!(:scale_id)
```

That throws "unknown attribute: scale_id" as an error. Possible I can't interact with the keys at all after the `CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|` ?

**Updated again**

I can see one reason why my above code won't work. I'm specifying a range for the fields in the row but hashes don't have an order. I've now tried specifying the keys that I want to deal with using indices but got undefined method 'indices'.

```
row.to_hash.indices(:name,:material,:release_date,:pcode,:notes,:set,:random,:quantity,:date_mask,:multipart)
```

I can't turn it into an array or I'll get stringily keys errors but I need to be able to specify which fields the create action should use so that I can use some for the Miniature create and some for the Size create.

My controller action by the way is as follows.

```
def import
    Miniature.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to miniatures_path, notice: "Miniatures imported."
end
```

**Update**

Here is the seed data I'm using to import

> name,material,release_date,pcode,notes,set,random,quantity,date_mask,multipart,scale_id
>
> A A A CSV test,Metal,03/01/2013,123123,Test notes,f,f,,6,f,1

With the above code, the error I get is

> "Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Material can't be blank"

but through trying things out I've had a variety of errors which indicate my `row.to_hash.slice` is not being parsed in the way the simpler `row.to_hash` is.

The expected result is either a successfully created Miniature object and a Size object OR an error on creating the size object because it can't infer the miniature_id from my using @miniature.sizes.build and wants more params. Can't debug that until initial slicing stage is passed/parsed.

Comment: Could you add some example or seed data? it would be more helpful for others to try out. Also put the unsuccessful result and the expected result with the particular object and data.

Comment: Updated my question with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assuming the keys to the hash are symbols like `:scale_id` but in fact they're strings like `'scale_id'` and this is where you're tripping up... you need to symbolize the keys if you want to use them as attributes to a create method.

```
symbolized_row = row.to_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
Miniature.create! symbolized_row.except!(:scale_id)
```

EDIT

Actually if you use `except` instead of the mutating `except!` then you'll have access to the scale id in subsequent lines.

```
symbolized_row = row.to_hash.inject({}){|memo,(k,v)| memo[k.to_sym] = v; memo}
Miniature.create! symbolized_row.except(:scale_id)
@miniature.sizes.build(:scale_id => symbolized_row[:scale_id])
```

Comment: Fantastic. I saw some references to turning them into symbols but didn't know you could just do that with the keys or that it was the solution to this problem. That makes the exception work. I still don't have a working build action for the Size object, that's giving "undefined method `sizes' for nil:NilClass" but that can be a matter for another question. Thank you so much.

Comment: I did wonder where the "@miniature" was being defined.  Is the `sizes` method/attribute supposed to be on the newly created Miniature object? In that case, perhaps you should do `@miniature = Miniature.create! symbolized_row.except(:scale_id)`  ... I'm not sure you need to use an instance variable, a local variable on those two lines would work fine.  If you use an instance variable, at the end of the method it'll only contain the value of the last miniature created, not all the miniatures, but then I don't know your app, maybe that's what you want.

Comment: I meant `@miniature = Miniature.create symbolized_row.except(:scale_id)`... again, better to avoid the mutable `create!` in this case, not needed and you can access the excepted data later.

Comment: Yes I realised that and changed it to `@miniature = Miniature.create` and it's working great although I've somehow made the objects read only and can't delete them. Am investigating. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Got that fixed too now fwiw. A join in a scope rendering the object read only. Fixed.